# Can't connect to JIRA-api via python-jira lib

Tags: python, jira-rest-api

I can't authenticate to python-jira
I try to use https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jira/ 
According to documentation I use

```
from jira import JIRA

jira = JIRA('https://pm.maddevs.co/') # I am not sure if it is correct to use our site server or jiras

username = 'my_user_name'
password = 'my_pass'
authed_jira = JIRA(basic_auth=(username, password))
```

I have mistake like

```
WARNING:root:HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=2990): Max retries exceeded with url: /jira/rest/api/2/serverInfo (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f8a7e228198>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',)) while doing GET http://localhost:2990/jira/rest/api/2/serverInfo [{'headers': {'X-Atlassian-Token': 'no-check', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Accept': 'application/json,*.*;q=0.9', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.18.4'}, 'params': None}]
WARNING:root:Got ConnectionError [HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=2990): Max retries exceeded with url: /jira/rest/api/2/serverInfo (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f8a7e228198>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))] errno:None on GET http://localhost:2990/jira/rest/api/2/serverInfo
{'response': None, 'request': <PreparedRequest [GET]>}\{'response': None, 'request': <PreparedRequest [GET]>}
WARNING:root:Got recoverable error from GET http://localhost:2990/jira/rest/api/2/serverInfo, will retry [1/3] in 17.18299613314676s. Err: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=2990): Max retries exceeded with url: /jira/rest/api/2/serverInfo (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f8a7e228198>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the following format to connect to server:

```
jira = JIRA(basic_auth=(un, pwd), options={'server': server})
```

So your code would be like this:

```
from jira import JIRA

username = 'my_user_name'
password = 'my_pass'
jira = JIRA(basic_auth=(username, password), options = {'server': 'https://pm.maddevs.co/'})
```