# How to View issue using JIRA SERVER API?(Through python)

Tags: jira, atlassian-sourcetree, jira-rest-api, python-jira, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I am new to Atlassian product(JIRA).So far I have tried multiple jira "CLOUD" api through python.And it works perfectly. Now I want to try the same API in jira "SERVER".
My doubt is?
1.Can I use the same code(jira cloud api) in server or it is going be completely different.If it is different please guide me regarding that.
2.Only the auth process is different for both cloud &  server.

#I am attaching my jira cloud api code(python) using HTTP Auth.

```
import requests
import json
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
auth = HTTPBasicAuth("username", "Api_Token")
def View():

 key=input("issuekey/issueid")
 url = "https://domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/"+key

 headers = {
   "Accept": "application/json"
 }

 response = requests.request(
   "GET",
   url,
   headers=headers,
   auth=auth
 )
#This is working perfectly in case of viewing the details of an issue(Jira cloud api).
```

**How do I modify the same code to work in jira server api?**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Python but auth can change between Jira Cloud and Server.

It depends what version of Jira Server you have. If it's before 8.14 instead of the token you need to add the actual password you would use to login the interface.
From 8.14 on, you should also be able to generate your own personal token from your profile, [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftware/jira-software-8-14-x-release-notes-1027133861.html#JiraSoftware8.14.xreleasenotes-tokens) some details

The endpoints are different, if you search in google "Jira API ", it should easily find the correct page. Something like [this](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/8.14.1/) one, you can't use the v3 endpoints you use for Cloud.

Be mindful of the base URL, if you login in your Jira with `https://<your instance>/jira` then you need the `/jira` when you call the endpoints
e.g. `https://<your instance>/jira/rest/api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}`

Comment: I tried to create a issue(JIRA-SERVER) using py client lib.
```from jira import JIRA
auth_jira = JIRA(basic_auth=('username', 'password'))
jac = JIRA('https://domain.atlassian.net')
new_issue = jac.create_issue(project='project key', summary='New issue from jira-python',
description='Look into this one', issuetype={'name': 'Bug'})```

Comment: I'm getting error like   ```WARNING:root:HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=2990): Max retries exceeded with url: /jira/rest/api/2/serverInfo (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000021175DD4220>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it')) while doing GET http://localhost:2990/jira/rest/api/2/serverInfo```

Comment: Is https://domain.atlassian.com the actual URL you are using? atlassian.com is a Cloud version of Jira. I'm not familiar with the error. But seems like you are trying to call a Cloud version of Jira with a Server API. If it was a Server version I would have expected something like https://jira.<your domain>.com

Comment: I found this other question with the same error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46148341/cant-connect-to-jira-api-via-python-jira-lib